# Tomcat 7. Images on server. Multiple contexts needed

Tags: tomcat7

I have a Rig project that has a Rig.xml deployed inside tomcat and looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\Workspaces\Jan2013\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Rig" path="/Rig" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Rig"/>
```

I would like to have another Context that would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\Work\images" path="/images" />
```

So that i can have the images in the path shown above and retrieve them onto my jsp using /images/FILENAME. How can i accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Almost done, just create "C:\Work\images" and the new context will be available.